# multiple instance of same file running, each instance log into different log file in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I have a master python script, that goes and automates configuring nodes in parallel in a distributed system setup in our lab. 
I run multiple instances of kickstart.py and it goes and configures all nodes in parallel. How do I create log handler such that each instance of kickstart.py configures each node separately in parallel and each instance logs into different log file. I want to use python logging module. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just add a [file handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler) to your logger, with some information derived from the name of the node in the filename to keep them unique?

Comment: Read `logging` documentation about it and you can crack it out - https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-from-multiple-threads

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the name of the desired logfile to the python script from the command line. Try something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
with open(argv[1], 'a') as logfile:
    #insert code here
    if something_bad_happened:
         logfile.write("Something bad happened!")
```

Note that python has some more advanced logging capabilities, but I'm not using them here for simplicity. You should probably use them.

Run this as `python kickstart.py log1` to log to a file in the same directory as the script or replace `log1` with a full path. I don't know how your 'master script' calls multiple instances of kickstart.py, but here's one way to call python code from python, passing command line arguments

```
import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(["python kickstart.py", "log1"])
0
```

Comment: Python has a `logging` library, no need to rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

`logging` module is thread safe and very easy to use.
Read the relevant [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-from-multiple-threads).

Here is a simple example:

```
import logging
import threading
import time


def worker(arg):
    logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
    while not arg['stop']:
        logger.info('Hello from thread')
        time.sleep(0.5)


def main():
    logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fh = logging.FileHandler('spam.log')
    fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(threadName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)

    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(info,))
    thread.start()

    for x in range(3):
        logger.info('Hello from main')
        time.sleep(0.75)

    thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which will give you:

```
2017-08-11 11:00:53,568 - simple_example - INFO - Hello from main
2017-08-11 11:00:53,568 - simple_example - INFO - Hello from thread
2017-08-11 11:00:54,069 - simple_example - INFO - Hello from thread
2017-08-11 11:00:54,318 - simple_example - INFO - Hello from main
2017-08-11 11:00:55,068 - simple_example - INFO - Hello from main
```